# What advantages are there to living in an urban monad?

Tags: society, cities, architecture

What advantages are there to living in an urban monad versus living in many spread out communities? What problems would this solve, and what problems would it create? How would society change?

Specifically, how does this help deal with over population?

Comment: Hello aurelien, welcome to Worldbuiding SE. This site is for the invention of *fictional* worlds to be used in stories, games, etc., and so I fear that your question is off topic. And even if it were on topic, you would need to explain the term monad. Surely you're not talking about linear algebra or category theory?

Comment: Welcome to Worldbuilding!  I don't mean to disuade you from participating, but look over some of the other questions first.  See any this terse?

Comment: The internet's urban dictionary for monad is not very pleasant either.  Without a definition of what it means this question is not answerable

Comment: @aurelien you know, you can still **edit** this question.  I’d still like to know what you are talking about.

Answer (score 1):

The premise of supporting a large mass of people in urban monads would take several generations just to convince them that this is the best option for survival. And then you would need to exert a ridiculous amount of control on the population in order to maintain peace. People who live in close quarters for long periods of time don't typically maintain a healthy mental state and will often become agitated and fight with neighbors. Gangs would likely form, creating their own 'territories'.

It is not human nature to 'share' the little resources that are available either. Instinct dictates that you keep for yourself and your family enough to survive or even thrive. Only in situations of attack (like in concentration camps) do we sometimes see this shift in human behavior. Not to mention that without the outlet of a natural environment, people's mental states will also suffer. This is why we take 'inner city kids' and send them to camp for a week in the middle of the forest.

The logistics of such ways of life would be a nightmare and near impossible to maintain for more than a few decades without it imploding in on itself.

Comment: Thus the only advantage would be for the people not living in the monad, as the urbanites kill each other off.

Comment: Since you seem to know what a *monad* is in this context, how about linking it?